# adb can't connect to 127.0.0.1:5555

Tags: vmware, adb

I was trying to follow the instructions provided in [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator/6058689#6058689) to the question of having a faster adb. However upon doing step 6, I run into the error `unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:5555`.

The only difference in my set-up from the one described in the link is that I am using VMware. During VM set-up, I didn't see any options to set-up a "Network: PCnet-Fast III", but it is already set to NAT. (Okay. Pardon me as I am not very comfortable with networking stuff yet.)

Doing netcfg gives me

```
lo   UP   127.0.0.1 255.0.0.0 0x00000049
eth0 DOWN 0.0.0.0   0.0.0.0   0x00001002
```

Any hints?

Thanks!

(BTW, sorry if linking to another thread/answer is bad form in StackOverflow. I'm used to forums discussion and, in the thread I linked to, I no longer see anyway to add a comment or something.)

Comment: I noticed that I have a XAMPP server running so I closed it. On eth0, I then got `eth0 UP 192.168.255.129 255.255.255.0 0x00001043`. However, trying to adb connect to 192.168.255.129 still produces the same error (with the ip host changed to 192.168.255.129, of course, but same port, 5555 .)

Comment: Another update. I installed VirtualBox and had PCnet-Fast III specified. Doing netcfg gives the same result as my comment above save that the IP for eth0 is now 10.0.2.15 . However, I still get the same error on both lo and eth0 IP addresses. Anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only 4 months late, but if you have a router at home (which is very likely), then use a Bridged Adapter, so that it becomes another device on your home network.  You can then

```
./adb connect 192.168.0.5
```

Comment: Wow. I've passed on this project already due to this problem (and the slow emulator, of course). And I've uninstalled the stuff needed to work on Android for other necessary libraries for another project. So, I cannot verify this. But well, it seems to make sense that our wireless router is the problem factor. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

oh i find answer. before use adb connect command most use adb kill-server command. see following url. thanks to all.
[android-x86.org](http://www.android-x86.org/documents/debug-howto)